# How can I view list of permitted params using Rails strong_parameters?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm in the process of migrating from a Rails 3 application up to Rails 4 and making the changes to strong parameters.  During this process I've been doing some command line debugging and would like to be able to view of list of all currently permitted parameters.

I was thinking this would work something like this.

`params.permitted?`

I've looked at the docs and googled, but have come up empty.

Comment: I'm using the debugger gem so I am within the context of the controller that I am trying to inspect.  So I have access to my params hash and can set permitted params such as `params.require(:foo).permit(:user, :etc)` and this will work correctly from debugger.  What I would like is to display everything that is currently permitted on the params at a given point in time.  The reason for this is I'm using engines that are setting params permit upstream as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Because `params.require(:foo).permit(:bar)` does not define a list of allowed parameters, but filters the `params` parameter hash at each request with the attribute names as arguments.

What you can do to see the list of allowed parameters is to take a look into your controller.

Another option might be to store the allowed parameters in a constant which can be queried from everywhere in your application:

```
# in the foos_controller
ALLOWED_PARAMS = [:bar]

def foo_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(*ALLOWED_PARAMS)
end

# elsewhere or in the Rails console
FoosController::ALLOWED_PARAMS
#=> [:bar]
```

Read more about how this filtering works: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

Strong params are typically defined in controller methods, which can't be accessed from the console...

Comment: You can access controller methods from the console like this `UsersController.new.index`. The problem though is that you do not have `params`, `request`and so on. Therefore the options in doing something useful are limited.